# xpages - is this direction a good one / view panel target

Tags: xpages

There is a Notes Client application which we want to rewrite it using XPages as we want to transform it into a XPiNC application. I will give you a simple example, explaining the Notes Client application:

There are one main form called ( let say ) `Company` and another form called `Persons`. From the company form the users can add multiple `Persons`. Of course, clicking the button `Add Person` from the `Company` form implies the current document ( `Company` ) to be saved - as the 2 forms have in common one field: `txt_CName`.

In the main frameset there is one outline entry containing a view ( which is categorized, based on this `txt_CName` ) to display the documents like this:

```
Company A doc.
    Person 1 from Company A
    Person 2 from Company A
Company B doc.
    Person 1 from Company B
```

I started already developing the XPiNC app. Regarding the `Persons` doc.: the users want completing the structure inside a dialog. OK ... but from the above view panel could I set the target to be computed ( when the link column is clicked ): Company A doc. to be opened in a normal way, but the Person 1 from Company A to be opened in the respective dialog - in other words to be computed. COuld you give me a simple example? Are there any other better solutions for my situation? ( excepting the classical functionality - from the Lotus Client app which I could developing using XPages )

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I'd second Chintan's suggestion, a Repeat Control is a much better idea. If the View Panel gives you exactly what you want, use it. If it's not, my advidce is don't use it. It will be harder to manipulate it to work how you want than to reproduce the styling using a repeat control. After all, a View Panel is just a repeat control that can only display contents in a table and only one entry per row in a tabular format.

It sounds like nested repeats - the outer repeat showing companies, the inner showing people - will make your job easier. For the second repeat you have access to the var property from the first repeat, so that makes it easy. And a link column just displays a column from an XspViewEntry using a Link control, so that's easy to reproduce. The look and feel of a View Panel can be reproduced easily enough - just look at the styles of a View Panel in Firebug and you'll see the classes to set.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm quite newbie in XPages development... I've never worked with nested repeats so far, but I have to use them ... great

Comment: It's well worth learning, repeat controls are something you will use a lot. The var property just gives you access to each element of the value property. So if that points to a dominoView, the var is an XspViewEntry

Comment: MFG Flay, learn repeats. They are not that difficult to work with. i would recommend sitting down with the Notesin9 sessions that explain repeats.

Answer (score 1):

I don't disagree with the nested xp:repeat approach.  Clearly repeats offer the most flexibility, however, they can be difficult to get your head around and then you need to  manage the entire "view" framework including view headers, footers, pagers, column headings, etc.

As a newbie you might consider the xe:dataView control as the parent view framework for the Company documents.  The dataView comes with is own built in repeat in its details facet.  Whatever you put in the details facet is repeated for each viewEntry in the dataView.  So, into the details facet you could add a xp:viewPanel control with a categoryFilter to display the Person documents for the Company.  Also, into the details facet add either an xe:dialog or xe:inPlaceForm control to create/edit the Person docs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Extension Library dialog box? I hope this small example helps you.

```
//test.xsp
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">

    <xp:inputText id="inputText1"></xp:inputText>
    <xp:button value="Show Dialog" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent("dialog1").show();}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
    <xe:dialog id="dialog1">
        <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:if(getComponent("inputText1"))
    if(getComponent("inputText1").getValue()!=null)
        return "The value is "+getComponent("inputText1").getValue();
    else
        return "";
else return "";         
    }]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:text>

    </xe:dialog>
</xp:view>
```

Here, the idea is that, whenever you open the dialog box, it gets computed. So, if I understand you right, you could create one dialog box and insert the custom control for person form within it and then link the fields based on the what is clicked in the frontend company document.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I need the dialog box to be opened when the link column from the view panel is clicked - with the specific fields values when these were completed. Also, the form Company contain an embedded view which lists all Persons documents for the respective Company.

Comment: You could set few session scope variables onclick event of linked column and then open the dialog box using "getComponent('dialogBoxName').show()"

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will try it. BUt, my view panel also contain some documents ( Company ) which I don't want to show them inside a dialog.

Comment: Ya, it could be handled based on conditions. Also, I would recommend you to use repeat control instead of view panel, it kind of gives you more flexibility and a better control over the documents.

Comment: Could you see my last question , please? It refers right to this issue, your above comment.

Comment: I am sorry, couldn't find it. Which question are you referring to?(I saw a few questions from you but all are answered) Can you post a link please..